# Почему происходит потеря информации при передачи из функции в функцию и как ее избежать?

Tags: c++, функции

Не так давно стал писать основную часть программы через функции. И столкнулся с проблемой, когда передаю значение переменной из одной функции в другую, программа его меняет на рандомное, либо обнуляет.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;


string text;

void mostRecent()
{
    int d = 0;
    string words[1000];

    for (int i = 0; i <= text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            //cout << "Выбрал isalpha(text[i]) " << endl;
            words[d] += text[i];
            //cout << "words[ " << d << " ] = " << words[d] << endl;
        }
        if (text[i] == ' ')
        {
            //cout << "Выбрал text[i] == ' ' " << endl;
            d++;
        }
    }
}

int main(string words)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    cout << "Введите текст: " << endl;
    getline(cin, text);
    mostRecent();
    cout << words[0] << endl;
    cout << words[1] << endl;
}
```

В данном отрывке кода, при передаче из *"mostRecent"* в *"main"* и выводе информации уже через основную функцию, на экране появляются рандомные знаки, вместо рабочих слов.

---

Я нашел для себя пока одно решение этой проблемы - создавать глобальные переменные и использовать их во всех фунциях.

Пока это все пишу, появилась мысль,конечно, я в ней не уверен, но все же. На это еще может влиять возвращаемое значение функции, допустим мне нужно использовать в функции *"main"* значение *d*, полученное в *"mostRecent"*, мне необходимо возвращать в конце функции *"mostRecent"* значение *d*.

```cpp
return d;
```

Но как тогда поступать, если мне надо, например в одной функции получить сразу 5 значений, которые потом я буду использовать повсеместно?

Comment: `getline`  --  ??

Comment: Начнем с того, что код не компилируется: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecc67b17aa1db7f3 `words` вообще не видно из `main`.

Comment: для начала  ознакомьтесь  с областью видимости.

Comment: Два разных `main`? Угу, как же.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, окей, код я подредактировал, чтобы все точно работало, я не думал, что это очень критично, тк вопрос в принципе не в самой программе, а в работе функций в целом

Comment: Написана какая-то белиберда. В вашем коде нет никакой "передачи информации" вообще. Код бессмыслен и некорректен. Никаких "рандомных знаков" он выводить не - код некомпилируем. Приведите мало-мальски понятное описание, о чем вы говорите.

Comment: @AnT я не знаю, как еще можно объяснить, что мне нужно получить и использовать значение массива words в функции main, если этот массив я заполнил значениями в другой функции.

Comment: Это можно сделать множеством разных способов. В том числе, как вы сами сказали, через глобальные переменные. О чём ваш вопрос? Вы рассказываете про какие-то "рандомные знаки", но ваш код даже не компилируется.

Comment: Код в Visual Studio работает, я не знаю, как мне его еще надо отредактировать, чтобы он заработал

Comment: GTmix, не может  представленный код работать нигде. Лучшеб  вы описали какое действие должна выполнять функция

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , функция на данный момент разбивает строку на слова. Просто я одновременно с написанием вопроса, продолжаю писать программу по заданию, и мой код уже выглядит совсем по-другому, в нем совсем другие задачи уже у функций. 
Мне нужно было чтобы в этой фунции строка дробилась на слова, а потом в main вывело 1 и 2 слова на которые функция подробила фразу

Answer (score 1):

Если вы все таки хотите хранить строки в массиве, а не в векторе( std::vector) или в другом контейнере, то, насколько я понел, вам нужно что то вроде такого:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
//функция вернет и массив строк(слов) и их количество
 std::pair<string*, int> 
 mostRecent(const string& text)
{
    int d = 0;
    string word, 
        words[100];
    /*нужно отметить, что есть много способов для 
      разбиения строки на лексемы(слова), но легче всего
      это сделать через строковой поток, следующим образом */
    std::istringstream stream(text);
    while (stream >> word) {
        words[d++] = word;
    }
     //у нас есть d штук слов
    //создаем массив в куче, чтобы могли хранить
    string* w = new string[d];
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
        w[i] = words[i];
    return std::make_pair(w, d);
    //массив  words будет уничтожен автоматически
}
int main() {
    std::pair<string*, int> p = mostRecent( "array of strings here" );
    string* words = p.first;
    int size = p.second;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << words[i] << '\n';
    std::cout << size;
    delete []words;
    return 0;
}
```

У вас много ошибок, и для меня легче было написать код, чем рассказать о ваших ошибках.

Answer (score 0):

```
void mostRecent(string *words)
{
    words[0] = "one";
    words[1] = "two";
    words[2] = "three";
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    string words[10];
    mostRecent(words);
    cout << words[0] << endl;
    cout << words[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: То есть, не выйдет массив объявить в mostRecent?

Comment: Передавать сырой указатель, а потом просто так обращаться к элементам с произвольным индексом? Какой-то медвежий ответ.

Comment: @GTmix, нет не выйдет, потому что массив уничтожается при выходе из функции, ну почитайте описание то немножко, что-ли